# Error using tptp_isabelle: Unknown logic "HOL-TPTP"

Tags: isabelle

I installed Isabelle2015 and I ran `Isabelle2015/Isabelle2015`.

When I try of using the tptp_isabelle tool I got the following error:

```
$ ./isabelle tptp_isabelle 10 foo.tptp
Unknown logic "HOL-TPTP" -- no heap file found in:
/home/asr/.isabelle/Isabelle2015/heaps/polyml-5.5.2_x86-linux
/home/asr/src/isabelle/Isabelle2015/heaps/polyml-5.5.2_x86-linux
```

Do I need to set up something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to build the HOL-TPTP session:

```
isabelle build -b HOL-TPTP
```

Comment: From your answer I realised that run `Isabelle2015/Isabelle2015` is not necessary.